# Finding a context-free grammar for the given language

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I am trying to find a CFG for the language A below.

I have spent hours on this but still could not find the answer. I also came up with the idea that this may not a context-free language but there is actually a PDA that recognizes it.

I would very much appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

```
  A={0^a 1^b 0^c 1^d| a+b < c+d, a,b,c,d>=1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to deal with inequalities like this is to start with a grammar for the equality, and then add one or more extra symbols.

Here's a simpler example, which might get you started. Let's look at the language

```
L = {0a1b0c | a+b < c, a,b,c ≥ 1}
```

We start with the language where the relationship between the lengths is equality:

```
L' = {0a1b0c' | a+b = c', a,b,c' ≥ 1}
```

Now, it should be clear that

```
L = {ω 0c"|ω ∈ L', c" ≥ 1}
```

In other words, `L` consists of a string from `L'` followed by one or more zeros. The original `c` has been split into `c' + c"`.

It's straightforward to write a grammar for `L` given `L'`:

```
L ⇒ L' 0
L ⇒ L 0
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
L ⇒ L' Z
Z ⇒ 0  
Z ⇒ Z 0
```

So now we just need to work on `L'`. Since we know that `c' = a + b`, we can replace `0c'` with `0b0a`, giving us:

```
L' = {0a1b0b0a | a,b ≥ 1}
```

That's revealed to be the combination of an inner language with the same number of 1s and 0s, surrounded by an equal number of leading and trailing 0s. In other words:

```
L' ⇒ 0 M 0
L' ⇒ 0 L' 0 
M ⇒ 1 0
M ⇒ 1 M 0
```

That gets you about half-way. Good luck with the original question.